# How to uninstall android apk without losing data?

Tags: android, backup, storage, apk

Is there a way to use adb uninstall on the apk, but make the data persist? I've lost the original key to my app, and now I would like to update it, but without losing the previous data. So I need to uninstall it first to add the new apk with the new key. Is this possible?

I forgot to mention I'm executing commands via a .bat file.

Comment: Can't you adb pull /data/data/<package_name> files and then uninstall?

Comment: @Shark I think I could do this, but can I do this using a .bat file? And insert in the device the same way I removed by using push?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch-friendly version.

```
My-make-clean.bat:
adb pull /data/data/com.blah.bla/file1 file1
adb pull /data/data/com.blah.bla/file2 file2
adb pull /data/data/com.blah.bla/file3 file3
...
adb uninstall com.blah.bla
adb install YourApkFile.apk
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: Should have specified, the following will work only for Android 4.0 and above.**

Just enable `adb` access, and use this command:

`adb backup -noapk -f /backup/myAppBackup.ab com.yourapp.packagename`

You should then have a file stored in your root directory (on Windows, your C:\ or equivalent) in a folder called backup.

Once you have this file, assuming the package name stays the same, you should be able to simply use the command

`adb restore /backup/myAppBackup.ab`

to restore the data.

Now, I don't know *for certain* that this will work once you've changed the key, but I'm fairly certain it relies only on the package name, so the signature key shouldn't matter. More info [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1420351).

Comment: Thanks, the first command created the backup, but it seems it isn't making the backup. I tried via adb shell and it says "unable to connect for backup"

Comment: Weird thing is I don't see the backup request screen in the guide you posted.

Comment: What operating system are you running? This only works on 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

If your data stored public,it will be remains after uninstalling,but if your data stored private,your data will be removed when you uninstall your App.

Answer (score -1):

If your device is rooted, you can access `/data/<package_name>` containing the app data, and you can make a backup of it.

If your device isn't rooted, you have no other means to keep your data.